# How can I install 22.04 onto Asus K541UA laptop

Tags: usb-installation

I have a laptop her from an elderly lady who wishes to use it for Facebook and Mail nearly exclusively. I wanted to install the latest LTS 22.04 via USB but I don't even get to the install main screen. It doesn't even boot on the stick.
Installing an older version (16.04) works but there still appears to be a problem that clogs the complete SSD with log messages in no time.
Has anybody some experience with this type of laptop? It used to run under WIN10.

Comment: does [this reference](https://www.systranbox.com/how-to-install-linux-on-an-asus-laptop/) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/q/1190764/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Answer (score 0):

Perusing through various sources I finally found the solution. It is rather easy, if you know it ;-)

You can install 22.04LTS on this machine. When starting from the USB go into the edit mode for the Grub option (press "e")+. Here you insert depending on the actual problems you are running into "nomodeset", in case of graphics problems AND / OR "pcie-noaer pcie_aspm=off" at the end of the line containing "quit splash" in order to get rid of the plethora of pcie errors and allow for normal booting.

If you cannot see the "Continue" button due to screen resolution just go to the first entry of the page, then hit and . This will bring you to the next step of the installation.

Once this is done and everything is installed go to /etc/default/ and edit the grub file (sudo gedit grub). Having done this run "sudo update-grub". This is it --- now Bob's your uncle :-))

Just in case the logfile of /var/log/syslog has grown out of proportion you can easily get it back to what it was when you installed. Enter into a terminal window and type "sudo tee /var/log/syslog </dev/null". This will completely clear all the entries from the file that were in there. Do the same for the Kern.log file and your system is lean again.