# Failed to install Ubuntu 22.04 desktop many times

Tags: boot, system-installation, 22.04

My laptop is Asus X541U 4GB RAM, 1TB HDD, 2GHZ Intel i3 6th gen CPU. In the grub menu I get the Try Ubuntu or install option. I highlight this option and choose the E keyword to get a command line and set "nomodeset", but still I get the tcp crb error and then failed to install live CD installer and then  many more  messages.

[image]

I used Rufus 3.19 to create a bootable USB and chose GPT format then. I have done this 7-8 times, but I still got the same issue every time.

Comment: 1. Verify the ISO, download again if necessary. 2. With Rufus assure the options UEFI/GPT are selected or try another tool for Windows like Balena Etcher. 3. You don't need `nomodeset` even if it has Nvidia and in any case there's the option "safe graphics".

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here, Arsalan:
[How can I install 22.04 onto Asus K541UA laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1418983/how-can-i-install-22-04-onto-asus-k541ua-laptop?noredirect=1#comment2472796_1418983)
I ran into a very similar problem end got it solved.
Good luck.